# Jquery UI Dialog with Backbone and Marionette

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm looking for a clean way to use jquery dialogs in the context of Backbone and/or Backbone.Marionette.

I want the exact functionality I have on [MY OTHER WEBSITE](http://www.discretefx.com) when user clicks Register" or "Log In". This is a site I built myself but it was when I was just learning jquery and the code is very spaghetti like with lots of DOM manipulation and not much structure. I loaded 3 separate jQuery dialogs into memory and used "open" and "close" to manipulate them.

Now I'm building a new site using Backbone and Marionette and want the same functionality but with better structure and less spaghetti code. I was thinking to only load ONE jQuery dialog into memory with a Marionette.Region inside of it, then just switch the View inside the region depending on which link was clicked ("Login", "Register" or "Forgot Password"):

in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<div id="dialog">
            <div id="viewContainer"></div>
        </div>
```

in BackboneApp.js:

```
App.Regions.ModalRegion = Backbone.Marionette.Region.extend({

    el: '#dialog',
    constructor: function () {
        _.bindAll(this);
        Backbone.Marionette.Region.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        this.on("show", this.showModal, this);
    },
    getEl: function (selector) {
        var $el = $(selector);
        return $el;
    },
    showModal: function (view) {
        view.on("close", this.hideModal, this);
        this.$el.dialog(view.dialogOptions);
        this.$el.dialog('open');
    },
    hideModal: function () {
        this.$el.dialog('close');
    }
});


App.Views.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    el: '#viewContainer',
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).load("/Account/Login", function () { });
        return this;
    }
});

var loginOptions = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, {
    title: "Log in",
    buttons: {
        "Log in": function () {
            //LOGIN POST
            Application.modal.close();
        }
    }
});

//Marionette Application
var Application = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

Application.addRegions({
    modal: App.Regions.ModalRegion
});

Application.addInitializer(function (startOptions) {

    $('#loginLink').live('click', function () {
        var loginView = new App.Views.LoginView();
        Application.modal.show(loginView);
    });

});
Application.start();
```

I'm having problems with this:

1. the render method of the view gets called twice.
2. the first time the dialog loads, you can see it being thrown into the DOM and then the dialog open animation runs.
3. The subsequent times the dialog loads, the dialog animation does not occur at all
4. Application.modal.close() does not trigger hideModal()
5. Not a problem but how can I attach each view's particular dialogOptions to the view? (to be referenced in showModal)

Yes, quite a lot of problems there but I'm sure they're related.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is a bit old, so it's using an outdated version of Marionette... but the ideas remain valid: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/17/managing-a-modal-dialog-with-backbone-and-marionette/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read the article I'm trying to apply it but running into problems. I updated my code and OP, I hope you can take another look and help.

Comment: Here is another comprehensive one, covering way more than Marionette but all your toolchain and environment. http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#backbone.marionette

Answer (score 0):

A method I've had to use in the past to get backbone/marionette to play nicely with iLightBox is the following:

```
onShow: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.iLightBox([
    {
        URL: '#competition',
        type: 'inline',
        options: {
            onRender: function(){
                console.log($('.ilightbox-container #competition'));
                self.$el = $(".ilightbox-container #competition");
                self.delegateEvents(self.events);
            }
        }
    }
    ]);
}
```

this changes the `itemview` to use the newly created modal dialog when it's rendered and then binds the events.